# Recreate pivot table (or table visualisation) as new table using DAX

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am a beginner in PowerBI looking to better understand the application and look for ways to upgrade the Excel dashboards that I made for a company of a friend. Therefore, I am trying to recreate the Excel dashboard in PowerBI. I am doing quite well so far with the other visualisation and the data model, but I am struggling to recreate a visualisation for which I had to create a Pivot table in Excel.

Although I can recreate the pivot table using the table visualisation, I would like to create an actual table using DAX such that I can use it for other visualisations as well.

I have a fact table called fJobs that has a structure:

| Date | OrderNumber | License plate | StartTime | EndTime | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 1 | plate 1 | 08.00 | 12.00 | 03.00 |
| 01-01-2021 | 2 | plate 1 | 11.00 | 12.00 | 01.00 |
| 01-01-2021 | 3 | plate 2 | 13.00 | 15.00 | 02.00 |
| 02-01-2021 | 4 | plate 2 | 09.00 | 15.00 | 06.00 |
| 03-01-2021 | 5 | plate 1 | 09.00 | 16.00 | 07.00 |
| 03-01-2021 | 6 | plate 2 | 08.00 | 10.00 | 02.00 |
| 03-01-2021 | 7 | plate 2 | 10.00 | 15.30 | 05.30 |
| 03-01-2021 | 8 | plate 2 | 15.30 | 16.00 | 00.30 |

As you can observe, for a particular day a license plate can be scheduled for multiple orders. Now I would like to create a table that calculates the utilisation rate is (having summed the duration of multiple orders for a truck on a specific day) for each day for each license plate. It would look like:

**Utilisation rate per day per truck**

| license plate | 01-01-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 03-01-2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| plate 1 | 0.50 | 0.0 | 0.875 |
| plate 2 | 0.25 | 0.75 | 1.0 |

Where the license plate column is a column of a dimension table (dTrucks), the dates are a column of another dimension table (dCalender) but these are now transposed and filtered on weekdays. The values are a sum of the duration of jobs per day for a particular license plate (truck), divided by 8 (working day).

I can recreate the latter table in PowerBI using the table visualisation with the following settings:

- values: dTrucks[License plate]
- Columns: dCalender[Date]
- Values: fJobs[Duration] divided by 8 (quick measure)

How would I go about creating such a table using DAX (new table) in PowerBI?Thanks in advance!

John

Comment: Are you familiar with the matrix visual?  I believe you can get your desired result without any additional DAX required.

Comment: I am familiar with the visual. However, I would like for the table to not be a visualisation, such that I can use the table for multiple other calculations as well. I feel like it would be smarter to create one table and use that for multiple visualisations, rather creating multiple visualisation that each have to make similar calculations.

Comment: If you want a table in your model that has the structure of a pivot table, the right place to do it would be in Power Query, which is designed to build the model and has out-of-the-box pivot and unpivot functionality.  But I'm not sure why you would want to do this.  Every month your table gets a new column and you'll have to go in and update the report to manage it.  Since your Duration column is an additive measure, the intermediate 'pivot' step really shouldn't give you any advantages over working with the table in it's original, lowest grain format.